# Why does MasterDetailPage.IsPresented not work?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using **Xamarin.Forms** to create a simple app using the *MasterDetailPage*. When I'm on my Master page I want to click a specific button to close the Master page. To do this, I use `IsPresented=false;` in my code-behind but it didn't work at my first try so I rewrote my components and the second time `IsPresented=false;` worked. I will post link to my github [repo](https://github.com/stanimirsp5/MasterDetailPage.IsPresented.git) with very simple sample code showing the working variant and not working, but most important part
from my parent `LiveLabel.xaml` I'll post here.

- Here is the not working `IsPresented` logic

```cs
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <pages:LiveLabelMaster x:Name="MasterPage"/>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

Here I have another component LiveLabelMaster.xaml and LiveLabelMaster.xaml.cs where is my logic

- Here is working `IsPresented` logic

```cs
  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
            <ContentPage Padding="10"
                     BackgroundColor="Gray"
                     Title="Master"
                     Icon="hamburger.png">
            <ContentPage.Content>
                <StackLayout Margin="5,30,5,5">
                    <Label Text="Master Page">
                    </Label>

                    <Button x:Name="b1"
                            Text="Close master page"
                            BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                            Clicked="CloseMasterPage"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentPage.Content>
        </ContentPage>

    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

Here I don't have another component my whole logic is here. And I think the reason it works is because I implement my whole logic at same component, but I don't know why.

Can anybody tell me why it works in one way, but on the other it doesn't?

Comment: please post the actual code for CloseMasterPage()

Comment: it's pretty basic                                                                                              `void CloseMasterPage(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            IsPresented = false;
        }`

Comment: IsPresented is a property of the MasterDetail page.  If this event handler is in the code behind of the CHILD page then it's not going to work.

Comment: Yes and from my child I'm trying to make new instance to parent  `var liveLabel = new LiveLabel();
liveLabel.CloseMasterPage(sender, args);`

Comment: creating a new instance won't do anything useful.  You need to have a reference to the **existing** instance that is already being displayed

Comment: Create a bindable bool and bind it to IsPresented, then toggle it on button click

Comment: From a new created App MasterDetail Page, do you mean that master page is showing.And you should set `IsPresented = false;` to close it ?You can share the 
full not working sample,I will check it. :)

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT no first from a new created App **detail** page is showing. Then I click menu button and **master** page is opened, where I have only one thing, a button. And when I press the button, I want **master** page to be closed. I have shared [link](https://github.com/stanimirsp5/MasterDetailPage.IsPresented) to my repo in github will this work for you?

Comment: @StanimirPetrov Hi, I test it in my local sample,when press button it closed.Sorry from your shared link ,can not be reproduced.If you have a complete not working sample.That will be better :)

Comment: Hey @stanimirsp, did you figure out what was wrong? I'm experiencing the same issue.